# Avoid Images re-rendering after loop in flatlist

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am using react-native-swiper library to create simple swiper.It is built over flatlist.

```
 <Swiper
      removeClippedSubviews={false}
      autoplay
      key={jsonMovies.length}
      loadMinimal={true}
      loop={true}
      loadMinimalSize={1}
      loadMinimalLoader={<ActivityIndicator />}
    >
      {Pages()}
    </Swiper>
```

After I set the loop to true , once the slide is completed , Images are re-rendered again when the slide begins again from first slide.How do I avoid the re-render.

I added the flatlist property  **removeClippedSubviews={false}** , still same issue.

Comment: Try with useMemo(), wrap image component in useMemo()

Comment: can u show me some example

Answer (score 0):

If your key jsonMovies.length change when the slide begins again it's normal, try to set a key that doesn't change between the loop.

If this is not the case, it could be a library design choice and the better approach is to use a cache system, such as:

https://github.com/DylanVann/react-native-fast-image